# Simultaneous task -Design Advice

Tags: design, workflow

I have to design the workflow where a user sets up multiple tasks that will run automatically.

Those tasks have two possibilities:

1. They do something simultaneously - Task 1 and Task 2 run at the same time.
2. First Task 1 runs and then Task 2 runs.

Any ideas on how I can improve the actual design so users know that they can set tasks to run at the same time, but also know there is a then option?

[image: mockup]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group all tasks that have to run simultaneously. Something like this:[image]

When "Add task" under "When complete..." is clicked a new task is created in a new 
group and the button changes to "Add simultaneous task" like the group above.

Comment: I think this is backwards.  I would expect all the separate, top-level groups of jobs to be simultaneous, and within each group for the jobs to be sequential.  But if your assumptions are right, I like this UI.

Comment: @Wildcard It's just an example that I created on top of the OP's image to explain the idea of grouping. But you might have a good point that the top down approach isn't ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, jaxXRo.
 It totally clarifies the 'And' and 'Then' sections for the task. I am just not convinced about the two boxes, I think it may look confuse if users decide to have workflows like 
A - Task 1 'And' Task1 
B - 'Then' Task 2
C- 'Then' Task 3 'And' Task 3

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If the tasks are always occurring either simultaneously (AND statements) or sequentially (meaning that any THEN statement is **always** occurring after or before any AND statements), then why not just have any THEN statements be a totally new step in the workflow?

It is also beneficial to the user to display the steps/tasks as actual text. When they want to edit it, then show them the dropdowns, but users understand if/then language more clearly as text than as a set of dropdowns and operators.

[image]