# Present a hierarchal view (tree) containing sequential and parallel tasks

Tags: grid, tree

How would you present a hierarchal view (tree) containing sequential and parallel tasks?

1. The tree can contain two levels of groups when each group can
   contain one or more tasks
2. A specific group can contain either sequential tasks or parallel tasks
3. The group could be collapsed and I still think we need a
   sequential/parallel indication in that case

Comment: Could you provide a visual of what is described? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/100272/simultaneous-task-design-advice/100284#100284

Comment: Can you show us how you have tried to solve this problem. Why do you think those solutions didn't work?